# Elastic search : how to get all data of specific field

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using the Java API. I want to know how to fetch only a specific field. I have tried this query in ElasticSearch Head plugin:

```
{"fields": ["name"],"query": { "match_all": {} }}
```

It's working. Now, please help me to write this using the Java API.

The equivalent SQL query would be:

```
select name from user;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the match all queries in Java api..

```
   QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery();
```

Refer http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/query-dsl-queries.html

I have created a git hub repository.. Refer to use the java client.https://github.com/sidharthancr/elasticsearch-java-client.

HOpe it helps..!

Comment: I don't want all field. I just want result for a single field.

Comment: Thanks. I got this. I was using hit.getSource() method instead of hit.getFields().. Thanks again..

Answer (score 0):

If you have a query already, all you need to do is something like this:

```
SearchRequest sr = new SearchRequest("your_index");
sr.source("{\"fields\": [\"name\"],\"query\": { \"match_all\": {} }}");
ActionFuture<SearchResponse> res = client.search(sr);
SearchHits hits = res.get().getHits();
```

You can also check out SearchRequestBuilder to help build the requests, but to me it's easier to build the query elsewhere and then plug it in like this.

If you don't know how to connect a java `client`, see http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/client.html

Comment: Thank you. but how to parse result? I tried
SearchHitField result = hit.getSource();
out.println(result);
but its printing null. how to get the value?